# MySQL query needs an additional page refresh to show UPDATE changes

Tags: php, mysql

Why does this not show the changes after submit?  The page has to be refreshed AFTER submission to see the changes.

```
$full_path = 'users/'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'/images/'.$name;

if($query = mysql_query("UPDATE user_info
                         SET user_image = '$full_path'
                         WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' AND
                         username = '".$_GET['username']."'
                         "))
                        {

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/'.$full_path)) {
        echo 'Got it!';
        }

    }
```

So, if I upload / click submit, the query is successful, but you can't see the changes until an additional page refresh.

Comment: Are you doing the update before or after you load the data for the page?  You likely need to do the update at the top of your page.

Comment: where is the code that display what you want to be displayed ?

Comment: I have it included in the <head>.  So, it's above

Comment: SOLVED.  I had the SELECT to display the image under the UPDATE.  So that was it

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case - nice find!

Comment: @Graham if you found the problem, post it as an answer and accept it so others experiencing the same issue can see.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore The answer would have really been helpful now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your update query is before your select for your data in the execution of the PHP page.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix your SQL, you are just leaving yourself open for SQL injection, with using `$_GET['username']` directly in your SQL query.

Please look at utilizing parameterization, also keep in mind that order counts when you develop these things. TOP -> DOWN.

If you have a display SQL call **BEFORE** your **UPDATE** call, then you will have to refresh again to see changes from the UPDATE SQL call.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a GET redirect after POST request anyway.